# How to make the contents of the address center-adjusted( change the default format of the address tag?)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume, addresses

I am trying to write my resume with LaTeX, and if you see the following image, the contents of the address is left-adjusted.

[image]

What do I do to make them center-adjusted?
The code I used is as follows:

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 
\begin{document} 
\name{\LARGE \bf MY NAME\\[12pt]} % the \\[12pt] adds a blank line after name
\address{ADDRESS STREET APT NUMBER\\ CITY, STATE ZIPCODE   \\ 
    PHONE-NUMBER }
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) have you tried `\begin{center}...\end{center}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\@tablebox` used internally by `res.cls` to typeset the name and address; the original definition is

```
\def\@tablebox#1{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}#1\end{tabular}}
```

and he'res the necessary redefinition:

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 

\makeatletter
\def\@tablebox#1{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\makeatother

\name{\LARGE \bf MY NAME\\[12pt]} % the \\[12pt] adds a blank line after name
\address{ADDRESS STREET APT NUMBER\\ CITY, STATE ZIPCODE   \\ 
    PHONE-NUMBER }

\begin{document} 

\begin{resume}
test
\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you should consider using a more modern class to typeset your CV? The [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) class is one of the classes available (you can get templates and examples [`here`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples)); other possibilitiescan be explored in CTAN: [`Writing Applications for a JOB/CV`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#applications).